# How to detect image location before stitching with OpenCV / C++

Tags: c++, opencv, homography, image-stitching

I'm trying to merge/stitch 2 images together but found that the default stitcher class in OpenCV could not handle my images.
So I started to write my own..
Unfortunately the images are too large to attach to this message (they are both 12600x9000 pixels in size).. so I'll try to explain as good as possible.

The 2 images are not pictures takes by a camera but are tiff files extracted from a PDF file.
The images themselves were actually CAD drawings, so not much gradients in there and therefore I think the default stitcher class could not handle them.

So far, I managed to extract the features and match them.
Also I used the following well known example to stitch them together:

```
Mat WarpedImage;
cv::warpPerspective(img_2,WarpedImage,homography,cv::Size(2*img_2.cols,2*img_2.rows));
Mat half(WarpedImage,Rect(0,0,img_1.cols,img_1.rows));
img_1.copyTo(half);
```

I sort of made it fit.. because my problem is that in my case the 2 images could be aligned vertically or horizontally.
By default, all stitch examples on the internet assume the first image is the left image and the 2nd image is the right image.

So my first question would be:
How can I detect if the image is to the left, right, above or below the first image and create a proper sized new image?

Secondly..
Currently I'm getting the proper image.. however, because I'm not having some decent code to check the ideal width and height of the new image, I have a lot of black/empty space in the new image.
What would be the best C++ code to remove those black area's?
(I'm seeing a lot of Python scripts on the net.. but no C++ examples of this.. and I have 0 Python skills....)

Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Greetings,
Floris.

Answer (score 1):

You can reproject the corners of the second image with `perspectiveTransform`. With the transformed points you can find the relative position of your image and calculate the new image size that will fit both images. This will also let you deal with the black areas, since you have the boundaries of the two images.

Comment: Ok, I managed to create the proper canvas by using the perspectivetransform like so:

Comment: Ok, I managed to create the proper canvas by using the perspectivetransform:

perspectiveTransform( obj_original_corners, scene_corners, homography);

Then I checked from both images the biggest and smallest x and y.
Having these, I could of course calculate width and height.

cv::warpPerspective(img_2,WarpedImage,homography,cv::Size(biggestX-smallestX,biggestY-smallestY));

Now, this creates a proper canvas size immediately even if the smallest X or Y from 2nd image are negative values.
The only problem is where to apply a shift if img_2 has a negative x or y.

?
Any ideas on this?

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087241/opencv-warpperspective or perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279008/specify-an-origin-to-warpperspective-function-in-opencv-2-x